# Why babel is throwing error Unexpected token import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Today suddenly it is not working.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Using babel 7.0.0 and it works quite well just yesterday.

It converted well

This is part of my project

```
dist (converted to ES8)
 -models
 -main.js
model
main.js
```

if execute `node ./dist/main.js`, `main.js` should uses models folder in dist folder. But, it uses models folder outside of dist folder.

I really want to know what the problem is.

Comment: Babel does not transpile `import`, that's what bundlers like webpack and rollup are for.

Comment: I've used webpack4 too. But I set that dist folder to create using babel